# PHP script Valid PayPal emails checker

Tags: paypal

I am looking for a way to check which of my costumers email addreses are linked to valid Paypal accounts before i decide to propose this payement method on my website. 
is there any PHP script Who check if email is registred on PayPal or no ?
i hav search in all forums but impossible to find this !

Comment: Nothing ! i am null on PHP, I hoped to find a script here.

Comment: We ask that you provide a minimum, complete and verifiable example (MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help with specific problems.

Comment: @RDay I would like a php script like this one : https://www.blackmon3y.com/

Comment: On the other hand I would imagine there is no method of checking if an email address has a registered PayPal account except by logging in with that account. It would be insecure to let anyone check if any email address has an account. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/seamless-checkout/ as a starting point.

Comment: @RDay You are right. It should never be possible to check that information. Sometimes it is possible to check if an email is registered by requesting a password reset. In a bad example, the website's answer will give away whether or not a password-reset email could be sent. In good examples, the websites simply state something like "if the email is registered, we just sent the reset link to it".

Comment: @BladeMadara Why would you want to do that? Many have different email addresses for various purposes. Whether or not you propose paypal as an option should not depend on the email address used to register on your website. Maybe someone is even willing to create a new Paypal account based on the option provided by you. Don't patronize your users.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to check if an email address is already linked to a registered PayPal account. This is not allowed for security reasons.